# Join query with comma separated values in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a table structure like

```
Table Name : crm_mrdetails

     id | mr_name | me_email     | mr_mobile  | mr_doctor|
     -------------------------------------------------
     1  | John    |abc@gmail.com | 9876543210 | 1,2      |

    Table Name : crm_mr_doctor

    id | dr_name     | specialization| product |
    -------------------------------------------- 
    1  | Abhishek    | cordiologist  | 1,2     |
    2  | Krishnan    | Physician     |2,4,5    |

    Table Name: crm_product

    id | product_name | unit| pts |
    -------------------------------- 
   1  | Crocin       | 50  | 50  | 
   2  | Crocin2      | 60  | 100 | 
   3  | Crocin3      | 30  | 90  | 
   4  | Crocin4      | 70  | 80  | 
   5  | Crocin5      | 80  | 50  |
```

I need to get data from "crm_mrdetails" table and join table "crm_mr_doctor" and "crm_product" ,joining condition like

```
crm_mrdetails.mr_doctor = crm_mr_doctor.id 
crm_mr_doctor.product = crm_product.id
```

But there is a comma separated values in column and i need output in below manner.

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [mr_name] => john
            [mr_email] => abc@gmail.com
            [mr_mobile] => 9876543210
            [doctor] =>([0]=>stdClass Object
                           (
                             [id] => 1
                             [dr_name] => Abhishek
                             [product] =>([0]=>stdClass Object
                                              (
                                                [id] => 1
                                                [product_name] => crocin
                                                [unit] => 50
                                                [pts] => 50
                                              )
                                           [1]=>stdClass Object
                                              (
                                                [id] => 2
                                                [product_name] => crocin2
                                                [unit] => 60
                                                [pts] => 100
                                              ) 
                                         )

                            )
                         [1]=>stdClass Object
                          (
                             [id] => 1
                             [dr_name] => Krishnan
                             [product] =>([0]=>stdClass Object
                                              (
                                                [id] => 2
                                                [product_name] => crocin2
                                                [unit] => 60
                                                [pts] => 100
                                              )
                                           [1]=>stdClass Object
                                              (
                                                [id] => 2
                                                [product_name] => crocin4
                                                [unit] => 70
                                                [pts] => 80
                                              ) 
                                           [2]=>stdClass Object
                                              (
                                                [id] => 2
                                                [product_name] => crocin5
                                                [unit] => 80
                                                [pts] => 50
                                              ) 
                                         )

                            )
                       )
         )
)
```

I need to write query in codeigniter to get output like above Please help me to achieve this result, Thanks

Comment: It would be much easier to use Foreign keys on your database. Otherwise your going to have to explode the comma seperated values.

Comment: I highly recommend you following the normalization rules by Edgar Codd. The first normal form he defines says "A relation is in first normal form if the domain of each attribute contains only atomic values, and the value of each attribute contains only a single value from that domain." And having `2,4,5` as a record is not following this rule, and making it very difficult now. What you need is a two column table for the relation between doctor and product, contains their id's.

Comment: To be blunt; Either normalise your schema, or don't bother with an RDBMS.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for showing me the right way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROBLEM**

As `@Liam Sorsby` and `@blckbird`  mentioned in there comments you should use normalization rules. Using comma separated values is not a good way and your tables are going to be more complex to manage when the size of data increases.

Just imagine "John" `(with id=1)` has got many doctors so your table would be something like this :

```
id | mr_name | me_email     | mr_mobile  | mr_doctor              |
 -----------------------------------------------------------------+
 1  | John    |abc@gmail.com | 9876543210 | 1,2,5,6,8,9,10,11,78  |
```

Now Imagine that you want to remove relation between doctor with `id=5` and Jhon `(user with id=1)`

1. You will have to get list of all the doctors who are related to Jhon
2. Explode the result
3. Search for `id=5`
4. Remove it
5. Implode the result
6. Save it to table.

Other operations like searching if a doctor and User have a relationship, adding new relationships and removing existing relationships becomes more complex using this architecture.

---

**BEST SOLUTION:**

Looking at the current scenario it seems like you have a `many-to-many` Relationship between a user and a doctor i.e *"A doctor can have many Patients and a Patient can belong to many doctors"*

In such case you should be using a "pivot table" to maintain relationship between two tables. In your case it would be something like this:

**Table Name: crm_mrdetails**

```
id | mr_name | me_email     | mr_mobile    |
 ------------------------------------------+
 1  | John    |abc@gmail.com | 9876543210  |
```

**Table Name : crm_mr_doctor**

```
id | dr_name     | specialization  |
-----------------------------------+
1  | Abhishek    | cordiologist    |
2  | Krishnan    | Physician       |
```

Now you will have a Pivot table to maintain the relationship between the two tables :

**Table Name : crm_doctor_mr**

```
id | dr_id     | mr_id  |
---------------+--------+
1  |  1        |   1    |
2  |  2        |   1    |
```

Same thing will be done for the Products and doctor's relationship.

products and doctors too have a `many-to-many` relationship- 
*"A product belongs to many doctors and a doctor has many products."*

so you will have a products table like so :

**Table Name: crm_product**

```
   id | product_name | unit| pts |
   ---+--------------+-----+-----+ 
   1  | Crocin       | 50  | 50  | 
   2  | Crocin2      | 60  | 100 | 
   3  | Crocin3      | 30  | 90  | 
   4  | Crocin4      | 70  | 80  | 
   5  | Crocin5      | 80  | 50  |
```

And a pivot table to maintain the relationship :

**Table Name : crm_doctors_products**

```
id | dr_id      | product_id |
----------------+------------+
1  |    1       |   1        |
2  |    1       |   2        |
3  |    2       |   2        |
4  |    2       |   4        |
5  |    2       |   5        |
```

Once You have made changes in Your Database You can query any record using simple Joins.

---

**ANOTHER SOLUTION**

If you are at a stage where it is not possible to make changes to DB You can use this solution however i would prefer the one above.

```
public function get_mr_details(){
   $mrArray = $this->db->get('crm_mrdetails')->result();
   foreach($mrArray as &$mr){
     $mr['doctor'] = $this->db->where_in('id',$mr['mr_doctor'])->get('crm_mr_doctor')->result();
     foreach($mr['doctor'] as &$dr){
         $dr['product'] = $this->db->where_in('id',$dr['product'])->get('crm_product')->result();
     }
     unset($mr['mr_doctor']); 
   }
   return $mrArray;

}
```

However this solution will cause multiple queries to run on database and will exponentially effect performance with the increase in size of data in above tables.

Hope this helps !!!

Comment: really appreciate your comment, Its my mistake going to change database schema. Thannks for correcting me,
Thanks all.